# How does the Token Verification approach works to prevent CSRF in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, security, csrf

i read about how to use the <@Html.AntiForgeryToken()> to generate an encrypted value in a hidden field, which will also match another value that is stored as a session cookie in the user’s browser.

But my questions are:-
1. will the value in the session cookie be encrypted also, 
2. and if yes then how the [ValidateAntiforgeryToken] on the action controller will know how to decrypt both values and match them?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the value in the session cookie be encrypted also

Yes. It represents a token. And it's the same value as the one used for the hidden field. Actually it's the `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` helper that does 2 things. It generates the token and puts renders it in a hidden field and it also sets a cookie with the same value.

> and if yes then how the [ValidateAntiforgeryToken] on the action controller will know how to decrypt both values and match them?

It uses the same encryption/decryption algorithm that classic WebForms use to encrypt/decrypt ViewState. It's a symmetric encryption algorithm based on the machine keys. That's why if you are running in a web farm you should ensure that you have the same machine keys across all nodes because if an anti forgery token was generated and encrypted on one node of the web farm it might not be able to be decrypted on another node when the POST request is sent if the machine keys do not match.